# How to add space and indentation?

Tags: spacing, indentation

I'd like to have the values spaced out more but I have no clues how to do so. Is there an alternative way to add the indentation and the spacing between the x values?

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{parskip} 
\begin{document}
    \centerline{Question 2}

    x =

    \hspace*{6mm} -1.5000   -0.5000   -0.8042
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You ask, "I'd like to have the values spaced out more". Just how much more? A fixed amount more? 10% more? 50% more? Wide enough to take up the entire width of the text block? Please be specific.

Comment: At present, your query is so broad to invite dozens of possible solutions -- none of which may actually be relevant to your typesetting needs. Please clarify your use case. E.g., do you need to typeset a row vector?

Comment: Maybe you could use the package : https://ctan.org/pkg/exercise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must include `\hspace` between every value. You can achieve an equivalent separation using `\hfill` or manage the distance between the values specifically using a measure as 1 cm o 1 in.

Here is the code

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{parskip} 

\begin{document}

\centerline{Question 2}

x =

 \hfill -1.5000 \hfill  -0.5000 \hfill  -0.8042

 \hspace{0.5cm} -1.5000 \hspace{1cm}  -0.5000 \hspace{1in}  -0.8042

 \end{document}
```

Here is the output
[image]

Comment: Perfect! thank you so much!

Comment: Unfortunately, instead of minus signs, the negative values are preceded by hyphens.  To get minus signs, the numbers have to be in math mode.

Answer (score 0):

There are so many different ways to do this.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{parskip} 
\begin{document}
    \centerline{Question 2}
\begin{equation*}% no euqaton number
x = \begin{array}{ccc}
-1.5000  & -0.5000 &  -0.8042
\end{array}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Very cool! Thank you very much!